# How do I copy a range of cells between worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error with at the last line of the for loop.

```
Dim iLastCol As Integer
Dim teamsWsht As Worksheet

Set teamsWsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teams")

iLastCol = teamsWsht.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For iCol = 2 To iLastCol

    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim currWsht As Worksheet
    Dim teamsRng As Range
    Dim currRng As Range


    iLastRow = teamsWsht.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row              
    dTeams.Add iCol - 2, teamsWsht.Cells(5, iCol).Value                     
    Set currWsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dTeams(iCol - 2))                
    currWsht.Range("A1").Value = dTeams(iCol - 2)                           
  
    Set teamsRng = teamsWsht.Range(Cells(7, iCol), Cells(iLastRow, iCol))
    Set currRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(iLastRow - 7 + 1, iCol))
    
    currWsht.Range(currRng).Value = teamsRng.Value 'error here

Next iCol
```

I get an error 1004 method range of _worksheet failed at the last line.

Comment: You didn't specify a worksheet when you set `currRng`

Comment: `currRng.Value = teamsRng.Value`.

Comment: I removed the set, but now I get the error 

Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I've also noticed that I need to set the active sheet before selecting the range + you can't select a range of cells that are empty, both giving me an issue with 

Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: I am still confused, I have made the edits as per the link and receive the same error, what is missing?

        Set teamsRng = Range(teamsWsht.Cells(7, iCol), teamsWsht.Cells(iLastRow, iCol))
        Set currRng = Range(currWsht.Cells(2, 1), currWsht.Cells(iLastRow - 7 + 1, iCol))
        
         currWsht.Range(currRng).Value = teamsWsht.Range(teamsRng).Value

with the

Comment: `currRng.Value = teamsRng.Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Set` at that line. `Set` is only used with objects.